# Python & MySQL error only when using a list

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, list

I am trying to add a list to MySQL from data that I input during the program. 
I keep getting this error code below and cant seem to figure out why? 
The second parameter "workouts" is a list that I append the values I ask the user for input.

"Failed executing the operation; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="xxxx",
  database = "workouts"

  workouts = []

  def uno():
    workout = input('What kind of workout?  ')
    x,y = "bike","run"
    if workout == x.upper() or y.upper():
        workouts.append(workout)
    else:
        print('Need to input either BIKE or RUN')
    #print(f'Congrats on working out! Lets keep going!')
def dose():
    x = 1
    while x != 0:
        try:
            duration = float(input('How long was your workout? '))
            workouts.append(duration)
            x = x -1
        except ValueError:
            print('Needs to be a float-- Ex: 54.23')

def cinco():
    uno()
    dose()
cinco()


sqlFormula = ( """INSERT INTO 
                lifts(WorkoutType, Duration) 
                VALUES(%s,%s) """)
mycursor =  mydb.cursor()

mycursor.executemany(sqlFormula, workouts)
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question as text. Screenshots are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! Just added it

Comment: First, you seem to be missing a `)` on your `connect` call and it appears you have all sorts of indentation issues. Are you sure you copied your code correctly? And how can we tell what you actually entered. You should output the `workouts` list. And if you are doing `executemany`, shouldn't `workouts` be a list of lists?

Comment: Sorry it must be when I copied it over it caused the indentation issues, my program runs normally with no issues when I don't call the execute many. I am also fairly new to python, so having a list of list will work?